# How to remove an array using input element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to remove element of array by pop() method & splice() method,
for example

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.pop();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;
```

my question is how do I do these actions through input element in html?
for example by create a button to toggle hide or show element of array
so I want to toggle between remove "Mango" for example and add it again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show and hide an element, pass values from javascript to html element using JavaScript (not jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986609/how-to-show-and-hide-an-element-pass-values-from-javascript-to-html-element-usi)

Comment: i.e. Once button is click, one element from the array is pop-out and again need to display the fruits. Is it like that?

Comment: any event you do the following things, click, mouseover,keypress, basically any event should trigger the function.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/how-to-remove-item-from-array-by-value

Answer (score 0):

Use `addEventListener`

Example, where `el` is your button or whatever, and `doSomething` is the function you want to be executed on click:

```
var el = document.getElementById('some-id'); 
function doSomething() {
    console.log('a');
}
el.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I am not quite sure how do I remove the "Mango" in the example above and reuse it again similar to toggle